# Wait before sendkeys in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm using **Java**, **Selenium**, and chrome for test automation.
I want to enter a text, wait for it to be displayed and then click on **TAB**, I want to avoid `thread.sleep`
so i'm using this code :

```
        WebElement societe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("AutoComplInputBoxfld_XSociete")));
        societe.sendKeys("Text");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        societe.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

But it leave the field blank and goes to the next element.

1. How can i fix it?
2. Is there a way to use explicit wait before sendkeys?

Comment: do not mix implicit and explicit waits.  (Stick with your wait.until bits for waits...)

Comment: i used the implicit wait to wait for the text to be displayed, so i can click on the TAB key

Comment: yes... don't do that.  You should not mix implicit and explicit waits.  Implicit waits will be set for ALL driver actions going forward... so they can and will conflict with explicit waits which use the same type of polling mechanism and ignores...

Comment: okay, i'll remove it. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: a lot of people confuse it for a standard wait (like a sleep), but it's a polling loop... so there's a bunch of 1/2 second sleeps there.  The loop will ignore certain exceptions for a period of time.  (just like the explicit wait except without testing for an expected condition...)  It's a global setting for that driver session.

Comment: btw, if this is the browser's auto-complete... you probably can't access that. (it's outside the sandbox)  If they implement their own (the "autocomplete" attribute will be "off"), then you can just test for existence of the text you are looking for.  However, you want to be sure to check for stale element exceptions if you intend to do anything with that found element.  (this can mean the choices are still updating...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element,"Textexpected))
```

Reference

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.String-

Or

You can try

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(element,"Textexpected))
```

Ps-ignore formatting  using device

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```java
WebElement societe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
Wait<WebElement> wait = new FluentWait<>(societe);
societe.sendKeys("Text");;
wait.until(webElement -> {
    String value = webElement.getAttribute("value");
    return "Text".equals(value);
});
```

you need to configure fluent wait to have certain timeouts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
WebElement societe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("AutoComplInputBoxfld_XSociete")));
        societe.sendKeys("Text");
        while(!societe.getAttribute("value").equals("Text")) {//wait}
 societe.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```